# how do to_date function in postgresql works?

Tags: sql, postgresql, to-date

```
select to_date('20170202','YYYYMMDD');
```

returns:

```
2017-02-02
```

but when i do:

```
select to_date('20172202','YYYYMMDD');
```

the output is :

```
2018-10-04
```

when the Month is wrong why don't it returns an error as in Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

I think here is a reason why this not causing an error:

> to_timestamp and to_date exist to handle input formats that cannot be converted by simple  casting. These functions interpret input liberally, with minimal error checking. While they produce valid output, the conversion can yield unexpected results. For example, input to these functions is not restricted by normal ranges, thus to_date('20096040','YYYYMMDD') returns 2014-01-17 rather than causing an error. Casting does not have this behavior.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-formatting.html

Comment: ok.. thanks for your answer .. but i really one it to return an error when the date is wrong  month>12 for example and day>32 .. how can i do this or what can i use

Comment: @Kamfasage - If you try to cast `select cast('20172202' as date)`, you will get an error

Comment: so i should do : 
' select to_date ( cast('20172202' as date), YYYYMMDD); '
this wouldn't work because the **to_date** function has as parameters text and text

Answer (score 2):

Now this command raise error (this issue was fixed in PostgreSQL 10):

```
postgres=# select to_date('20172202','YYYYMMDD');
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "20172202"
```

Answer (score 0):

i have an answer of what i wanted/ 
i used the **to_char** instead of **to_date** an i cast the fisrt parameter into date..

```
select to_char(DATE '20162202,'YYYYMMDD') into datResult ;
```

so i can now have an error..

thanks for your help you all

Answer (score 0):

`YYYYMMDD` has to be `YYYYDDMM` months can not be greater then 12.